# Adding item to cart with BigCommerce Stencil

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

This question is specific to BigCommerce Stencil. Is it possible to use 'cart-item-add' hook outside of product context?

Right now when user adds product from 'product card' they get sent to cart. I'd like to change that behaviour.

Comment: Are you wanting to fire an event or listen for an event?

Comment: @Alyss  I guess what I'm asking is does `{{add_to_cart_url}}` fire the cart_item_add event?  And if not will `utils.api.cart.itemAdd(productId...` work with just the product id? I'm trying to add an item to the cart from the product card via ajax similar to when you're on a product page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with utils.api.cart.itemAdd()

The issue was my add to cart form action.  In the product card I needed to use `{{add_to_cart_url}}"` instead of `{{product.cart_url}}`

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting this to work. What did you use for the options object? Here's my code: `const productId = 114;
            const quantity = 1;
            const options = {};
            utils.api.cart.itemAdd(productId, quantity, options, (err, response) => {
                alert("added");
            });`